# Вставить фа иконку в код JS

Tags: javascript

Есть часть JS кода куда нужно вставить FA иконку `{"class":"cbp-popup-close",title:"Закрыть окно","data-action":"close"}).appendTo(b.navigation),b.nextButton=a("<div/>",` иконка вида `<i class="fa fa-circle-thin" aria-hidden="true"></i>` подскажите как правильно оформить что бы все было валидно. Я только учусь и не понимаю все это. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Добавляйте воспроизводимый пример с html, css и js. По куску\отрывку кода тяжело помочь.

Comment: Этот кусок кода на сайте формирует див такого вида: <div class="cbp-popup-close" title="Закрыть окно" data-action="close"></div> мне нужно что бы в конечном счете было так примерно: <div class="cbp-popup-close" title="Закрыть окно" data-action="close"><i class="fa fa-circle-thin" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>

Comment: https://qa-help.ru/questions/kak-vstavit-ikonku-v-knopku

Comment: спасибо - помогли девочке)

Comment: Под вопросом есть кнопка "Править" - нажмите на нее и отредактируйте вопрос, добавив необходимую информацию. @MaximLensky ответы - в ответы!)

Answer (score 1):

```
{"class":"fa fa-circle-thin cbp-popup-close",title:"Закрыть окно","data-action":"close"}).appendTo(b.navigation),b.nextButton=a("<div/>"
```

Всем спасибо.